# Thunderbolt and USB logo on screen

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I was trying to refresh my MacBook Air because I had just purchased a veikk A15 pen tablet and was trying to connect it to my MacBook Air. The instructions told me to refresh my MacBook Air and so I did. But then a USB and thunderbolt logo appears on my screen and won’t load my computer. This MacBook Air as no thunderbolt or USB port.

[image]

What has happened to my Mac?

Comment: All Macs have either a USB or thunderbolt port (unless you go back to the days before thunderbolt ever existed and FireWire was King). Could you edit this to ask a clear question? What do you want to do here other than realize you’re in target disk mode instead of booting to an OS.

Answer (score 1):

These symbols are displayed when a Mac boots into target disk mode. Usually you activate it by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> at startup ([different startup key combinations)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255). Another option is to go into `settings` → `startup disk` → `target disk mode`.

You can simply restart your machine and it should boot normal. If it does not, disconnect all peripherals (mice, keyboards,...) and try again.

Target disk mode makes your internal hard-drive accessible to connected Macs via Thunderbolt/FireWire. Read more about target disk mode [here](https://iboysoft.com/howto/target-disk-mode-mac.html) or [here](https://www.remorecover.com/blog/what-is-target-disk-mode-how-and-when-to-use-it-on-your-mac).

---

If this still boots into target disk mode, then your <kbd>T</kbd> is broken and continuously sending a `pressed` state to your MBA (MacBookAir) which can only be solved by repair.

---

Note: I assume by *refresh* you mean reboot.

Comment: Excellent answer and it may do all the OP asks, but I’m going to put a hold on this to clarify what they want in the end.